# Bootstrap 3 with Less - How I manage to center the container horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm trying to build a webpage with the bootstrap 3 framework and the less tool.
For one special page I'd like to center the container horizontally and vertically. I know there are allready some questions out there, but for me they do not work.
So this are the solutions i've tried following:

HTML:

```
   <div class="container hvcenter" > <!-- Container -->
     <div class="row"> <!-- Bootstrap Row -->
       <div class="col-sm-4">
         <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-7">
         <p>Textblock ... </p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    max-width: 85%;
    padding-top: 3em;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: @border-radius-large * 6;
}

.hvcenter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

This effects thath the div is centered horizontally, but not vertically.

An other try was to build in one mor class for vertical alignment and to use the builtin solution for horizontal alignment (.center-block):

HTML:

```
   <div class="container center-block vcenter" > <!-- Container -->
     <div class="row"> <!-- Bootstrap Row -->
       <div class="col-sm-4">
         <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-7">
         <p>Textblock ... </p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    max-width: 85%;
    padding-top: 3em;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: @border-radius-large * 6;
}

.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-alignment: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

I'm happy about every answer. Thanks for spending time on this.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: @RedDevil thx for this link. That was the perfect solution for me. Now it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```css
        
        .container {
    max-width: 85%;
    padding-top: 0;
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: @border-radius-large * 6;
}

.vcenter {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height:10em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container center-block" > <!-- Container -->
     <div class="row"> <!-- Bootstrap Row -->
       <div class="col-xs-4">
         <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-7 vcenter">
         <p>Textblock ... </p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try flex. Check out this link:
https://jsbin.com/pezesaquza/edit?html,css,output

[image: JSBIN Example]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. But I'm sorry this doesn't work for me. Maybe my question was not concrete enough. I have one row with two colums in the container. The two colums have the same height. What I want to do, is to get this row (or the whole container) centered horizontally and vertically.